# Python - How do I make it so that my other program only executes when an if statement is in agreement?

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, import

My program is meant to make some sort of online cookbook and depending on what I want to make, I can choose which program to execute. In order to finally have got it to work, the integer I type in will correspond to the code that I want to run:

```
enter code here

cookbook = int(input("What recipe would you like to make? (Please state the number)\n"))
if cookbook == 1:
    import mymodule as mx
    mx.greeting("Nana")

    a = mx.person1["age"]
    print(a)

    mx.omin(2)

    mx.tmin(4)

    mx.cmin(10)

    mx.smallest(0)
else:
    print("Updates pending")
```

Comment: This code should work, but make sure that `import pepper` is indented.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to change which python file you are going to run. You could do this simply by changing the namespace from the imports.

```
cookbook = input("What recipe would you like to make?")
if cookbook == "pepper":
    import pepper as recipe # This is the name of the file I want to execute
elif cookbook == "pasta":
    import pasta as recipe

recipe.run()
```

There can be more elegant ways to do it, and use the name itself to load the file directly, but I think this is closest to what you were trying to do.

Here is an example with 3 files, as I understand what you are trying:

cookbook.py

```
cookbook = input("What recipe would you like to make? ")
if cookbook == "pepper":
    import pepper as recipe
elif cookbook == "pasta":
    import pasta as recipe

recipe.run()
```

pepper.py

```
def run():
    print('\n1: Grow plant')
    print('\n2: Get pepper')
```

pasta.py

```
def run():
    print('\n1: Mix water with flour and egg')
    print('\n2: Flatten')
    print('\n2: Boil in water')
```

You then run `cookbook.py` and type either 'pepper' or 'pasta'

Comment: Another problem that I have is that now, it says that "pepper" hasn't been defined

Comment: @newdevclueless did you make a file called pepper.py ?

Comment: @ 001001 I have. It's the main file that I have so far

Comment: @newdevclueless you need to run a different file. importing itself doesn't make sense

Comment: I've followed your instructions word for word and even copied to double-check but I still get an error when I run it on cookbook.py: File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pepper' is not defined

Comment: @newdevclueless you need to make the other files as well, and they need to be saved in the same location

Comment: I have saved them all in my python folder on my desktop along with my other python files or should I make another folder within that folder?

Comment: @newdevclueless you will need to provide more information on your filename or structure of why your output is giving you the error. It seems you are having issues running python code in general.

Comment: i use python 2.7.17 on an old macbook. the pepper program i referred to before works perfectly fine on its own or if its file is imported at the beginning. I have made new files and changed the names to reflect what you have told me.

Comment: @newdevclueless you are doing something besides my example, as you have a name error for pepper. I am not sure I can help much more on this point than just saying you should copy the example exactly as described.  Also use python 3, python 2 is dead.

Answer (score 0):

What helps is that instead of using words to select which option is to be imported, use numbers and tell the user that in the question. Functions don't seem to be able to process user input, so input it in the code before running as in "mx.omin(2)".

```
cookbook = int(input("What recipe would you like to make? (Please state the number)\n"))
if cookbook == 1:
    import mymodule as mx
    mx.greeting("Nana")

    a = mx.person1["age"]
    print(a)

    mx.omin(2)

    mx.tmin(4)

    mx.cmin(10)

    mx.smallest(0)
elif cookbook == 2:
    import sauce as mx
    mx.greeting("Nana")

    mx.cabmin(0.6666)

    mx.carmin(2)

    mx.cookmin(200)

    mx.smallest(0)

    mx.confidence("OK")

    mx.final("sauce")
else:
    print("Updates pending")
```